# Change parent div on input[type=checkbox]:checked with css

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors, checked

I can figure out how to make the parent div change when checkbox is checked :(
Changing the following paragraph works fine.

Tried this approach without luck in Chrome:

**HTML**

```
​<div>
    <input type="checkbox​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​" checked>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: pink;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
}
div + input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + p {
    background: blue;
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/lajlev/3xUac/

Comment: I hate when people mark as duplicate what the question they use and the duplicate doesn't even have an answer or publicly voted up answer.

Comment: If anyone still search for a solution, this can help: https://jsfiddle.net/eduardoks98/wv0amod8/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No way to select a parent with CSS only (until CSS4), so you must use JS..

See this post that talking about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1384214).

Comment: Keep in mind that the [new draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) uses `!` instead of `$` to specify the subject of the selector.

Comment: This jQuery plugin claims to add the behavior to your stylesheets: http://demo.idered.pl/jQuery.cssParentSelector/

Comment: I've tried out the jQuery plugin without luck, looking forward to the new CSS4 selector.

Comment: Or you can directly use something like http://lesscss.org for example !

Comment: i don't think it'll be in CSS4. because it CSS is have cascade style, which means you can climb up, you can just go down

Answer (score 8):

You cannot access the parent but if you reorganize your html code and make the `input` and `div` elements siblings then you can try this:

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

div p {
  color: black;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+div {
  background: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+div p {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<div>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

[external link](http://jsfiddle.net/tenben2/dvuwgaq1/)

Comment: <div>
   <p>Test</p>
</div><input type="checkbox" checked>  // is this possible ?

Comment: @hanu not really, the `+` defines the next element, there is nothing to access the previous sibling.