# change css style of span that has checked input child using CSS

Tags: css

I want to change span background image when it's child input is checked, any way to do that using CSS?

```
<span style='background-image:'url(bla bla)''><input id='child'/>span to be changed</span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change parent div on input\[type=checkbox\]:checked with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846127/change-parent-div-on-inputtype-checkboxchecked-with-css)

Comment: no, it's not give me answer it's suggest to use (:has) that is not supported by any browser

Comment: That's an autogenerated comment by StackOverflow when a question is marked as a duplicate. I wasn't suggesting there's an answer, I flagged this as a duplicate of a question that has been asked many times. The answer is currently, no. You will need to use Javascript to make that happen in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.
Anyway you can use `:has()` pseudo-class, that [is still not supported by any browser.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has) .
With `:has()` your code will be something like this:

```
span:has(> #child.checked) { /* styles */ }
```

But the best thing is to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: ok but it's still not supported by all the browsers.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
You must use JavaScript

Comment: Desolate, but there are no other ways in css

Answer (score -1):

Here is one trick to achieve the goal without `:has`

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}
#child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#child:checked:before {
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span style='background-image:'url(bla bla)''><input id='child' type="checkbox"/>span to be changed</span>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587669/8620333 .. your code will not work in Firefox

Comment: it can be overcome